# Check if column contains specific values in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I need to check in excel whether a column (b1:b300) contains only 2 specific values 1,-24. How can check this using formulas only. Please help

Answer (score 9):

You can use a VLOOKUP, and depending if you search for ANY of the two or BOTH of the two, you combine two VLOOKUP as needed.

`=VLOOKUP(arg,range,1,FALSE)` will yield `#N/A` if not found, which can be further analyzed using the `=ISNA()` function

Comment: This was a perfect example where I was pulling a value for comparison but it was still pulling a previous cells value if it was N/A. The countifs function would work, but this is so perfect!

Answer (score 5):

It is simple:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B300,"<>1",B1:B300,"<>-24")
```

Comment: +1 noting that this approach works in xl07/10 (version not specified in question) by counting exceptions

Comment: Yes, the countifs function should only be applied to 2007 and higher version