# In Excel how do you look at a series of cells and evaluate where a value exists and then give a result based on this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of cells which have formulas which give a result of "Pass" or "Fail". I want to look at this series of cells and if there is a "Fail" in any of them give a result of "Uncalibrated" and if they are all pass give the result of "Calibrated".

i.e. i want to look at a range and ask if it contains certain value then...

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7468861/2258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(G1:G100,"Fail")>0,"Uncalibrated","Calibrated")
```

or

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("Fail",G1:G100,0)),"Calibrated","Uncalibrated")
```